# how do i prevent loading of hidden HTML tags? Or deleting them totaly from the page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I asked this question before but never got the answer which worked,

I have this input fields :

```
<form method ="post" action="select.php">
<input id="nol" style="width: 350px;" type="text" name="searchdisease" placeholder="type diagnosis one"> 
<input class="btn btn-success" style="width: 120px; margin-right: -90%; margin-left: 9%;" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

which posts user input on to the next page,on that page i fetch data from  a DB based on user input and echo to a select tag:

```
$search_disease = $_POST['searchdisease'];
$query="SELECT diagnosis, ICD10 FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease%'";
$result= $con->query($query);
```

but before i echo, i check if the post contains any values and if not then disable,hide then remove all such select tags

```
<?php 
if(strlen($_POST['searchdisease']) == 0){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">$("#disease").remove();</script>

    <select id="disease" style="width: 40%; display: none;" disabled="disabled" name="tdisease-remove">

    <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#tdisease-remove" ).remove();

    </script>
    <?php } else { ?>

<select id="disease" style="width: 40%; position: relative;left: 100px; right: 200px; left: -5px;" name="tdisease">

     <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
<?php } ?> 
     </select>
     <?php } ?>
```

but this drop-down is not being removed, it just loads data in the background which affects performance, so i want to know is there a way which i can prevent it from loading immediately after php checks user input for values?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the tag with Javascript, just don't create them in the first place.

Comment: okay i created it because its a billing app that i am trying to make, so at times the user will not use some input fields based on the number of diagnosis he or she wants to make, but at times he or she will use all of them so in times he does not need to use all of them i want to remove them based on the user input

Comment: You're deleting the `disease` input field and then recreating it. That means there's some earlier code that's creating the input field. Just change that earlier code so it doesn't create it.

Comment: no that disease drop will only show if the user wrote something in the input field else if he did not then delete it

Comment: But right after you delete it, you have `<select id="disease" ...>` which adds it back.

Comment: yes its an if/else statement

if there is no input delete the tag
else if there is input then create it

Comment: In the `if` you delete it and then create it again. In the `else` you just create it without deleting first. Don't you see that `<select id="disease"` is in both blocks?

Comment: oh! yah i see it, so you saying i should just leave the one in the if block? right?

Comment: Take out the one in the `if` block.

Comment: the reason why i included the if statement was to create the drop-down based on user input so if i take it out that functionality is gone

Comment: I didn't say to take out the `if` entirely. Just take out the code that creates `<select>` in the `if` block.

Comment: thank you many times, do you mind making this an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the code in the `if()` block that adds the `<select>`. It just needs to delete `#tdisease-remove`.

```
<?php 
if(strlen($_POST['searchdisease']) == 0){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#tdisease-remove" ).remove();
    </script>
    <?php } else { ?>

<select id="disease" style="width: 40%; position: relative;left: 100px; right: 200px; left: -5px;" name="tdisease">

     <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
<?php } ?> 
     </select>
     <?php } ?>
```